# Erro ao validar login e redirecionar para home

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou utilizando o wamp 2.4 e tentando implementar um login em AngularJS. Porém, quando clico no botão `submit` ocorre o *refresh* da pagina mas ela não muda para a *home*.
A sessão é sempre gravada mesmo estando incorreto o usuário e senha.

Abaixo a parte do código que está com erro:

**`loginService/js:`**

```
'use strict';
app.factory('loginService',function($http, $location, sessionService){
    return{
        login:function(data,scope){
            //o erro ja comeca no retorno da session
            var $promise=$http.post('http://localhost/estudos/app/data/user.php',data); //send data to user.php
            $promise.then(function(msg){
                var uid=msg.data;
                if(uid){
                    //scope.msgtxt='Correct information';
                    sessionService.set('uid',uid);
                    $location.path('/home');
                }          
                else  {
                    scope.msgtxt='incorrect information';
                    $location.path('/login');
                }                  
            });
        },
        logout:function(){
            sessionService.destroy('uid');
            $location.path('/login');
        },
        islogged:function(){
            var $checkSessionServer=$http.post('http://localhost/estudos/app/data/check_session.php');
            return $checkSessionServer;
            /*
            if(sessionService.get('user')) return true;
            else return false;
            */
        }
    }

});
```

**`user.php:`**

```
<?php 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Auth-Token,Authorization,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE');

    $user=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));  //get user from 
    //nao esta respeitando a validacao
    if($user->mail=='teste@teste.com' && $user->pass=='1234') 
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['uid']=uniqid('ang_');
        print $_SESSION['uid'];
?>
```

**`app.js:`**

```
'use strict';
// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
var app= angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', controller: 'loginCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'homeCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
}]);


app.run(function($rootScope, $location, loginService){
    var routespermission=['/home'];  //route that require login
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
        if( routespermission.indexOf($location.path()) !=-1)
        {
            var connected=loginService.islogged();
            connected.then(function(msg){
                if(!msg.data) $location.path('/login');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Não consegui encontrar onde está o erro.

Comment: Adicione o `loginCtrl` à pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri o erro.

Estava utilizando o localhost gerador pelo grunt localhost:9000 quando deveria utilizar o localhost do wamp localhost.

Utilizando o localhost do wamp a session foi retornada corretamente.
Espero que está questão auxilie quem utilizar como base o vídeo do Almine Elgali.